# Solving a 3x3 system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following system of equations:

> \begin{cases} 
>       2x+y+z=4 \\
>       -x+2y+z=1 \\
>       x+y+3z=6
>    \end{cases}

The results I found were $x=1,y=0,z=2$. However, I'm not sure about my answer. Could I get some guidance?

Answer (score 1):

If you have found a solution, the fastest way to check if it is a valid solution is by substituting it back into the original system.

$$1+0+3(2)=7 \ne 6$$

Hence it is not a valid solution.

To solve the problem, you might like to find its reduced row echelon form.

Comment: Why  must be 6 to this?

Comment: the third equation, the right hand side is $6$ right? the meaning of a solution means it satisfies all the equations.

Answer (score 0):

Let check directly plugging the solution into the system to see that something is wrong.

By Gaussian elimination we have

$$\begin{cases} 
      2x+y+z=4 \\
      -x+2y+z=1 \\
      x+y+3z=6
   \end{cases} \to \begin{cases} 
      2x+y+z=4 \\
      5y+3z=6 \\
      3y+4z=7
   \end{cases}\to \begin{cases} 
      2x+y+z=4 \\
      5y+3z=6 \\
      11z=17
   \end{cases}$$

which is easier to solve (find $z$ from the third equation then $y$ form the second and finally $x$ from the first one).

Answer (score 0):

No, your solution is not correct. We can see this by plugging in your solution into equation 3, which produces $$1+0+3\cdot2=6\to7\neq6$$-- a clear contradiction. So how can we solve this? Normally, we tend to solve large systems with Gaussian Elimination, but since this is small enough, we can do it by hand.

We first negate equation 3 and add all three equations together to get $$2y-z=-1$$Next, we add equation 2 to equation 3 to get $$3y+4z=7$$With our two new equations, we can multiply the first by 4 and add them together to get $$11y=3\to y=\frac3{11}$$So, we can plug in this value of $y$ into the system as a whole, and now we can solve the system as it is in two variables.